# Is it correct to say 'Something is nostalgic'?

Tags: word-usage, word-in-context

This is a sentence I've tried to make:

> We used to visit our grandmom in the summer; those halcyon days are so
> nostalgic.

What makes me doubt is that **nostalgic** often comes with **feel**, and in this case, I don't use **feel**. Does my sentence sound OK? I need your correction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The time is not nostalgic - **you** are nostalgic about it.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks for your comment. What if I say: those halcyon days make me feel nostalgic? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @user516076 Kate's advice is not quite correct. Nostalgia is a feeling, but the adjective 'nostalgic' can describe other things too. Like I said in my answer, it can describe anything pertaining to nostalgia. You can say that a past time IS nostalgic for you, as a memory.

Comment: Indeed I think Astralbee is correct. A contemporary film about the 60s can be `a nostalgic feel-good romp` and at the same time is can `evoke nostalgic feels *about* the 60s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can say that things are nostalgic. Although the noun *nostalgia* itself is a feeling, Webster's dictionary gives a secondary definition of the adjective 'nostalgic' as "*pertaining to nostalgia*". So if something provokes feelings of nostalgia, it could be said to be nostalgic.

Cambridge contains this example:

> We'll take **a nostalgic look** at the musical hits of the 60s.

I don't see any problem with your example - the days of the past are nostalgic for you, so you can rightly describe them as such. You even got the tense correct, because you said 'those days *are* so nostalgic'. It would be incorrect to say they 'were' nostalgic because they weren't at the time, but they are now as you look back on them.

You could even talk about future days as nostalgic - one travel website I found offers "nostalgic days out", that is days which will provoke nostalgia for the past.